# SSIS 2017 scripting language?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to plan for the future for our Data Warehouse department.  We use microsoft SQL 2014 & SSIS and have some scripts in C#.  Will sql 2017 or the next version stilll use C# or will it use asp.net core? or some other language? thank you.

Comment: You better ask this on Microsoft resources. The answer they may provide would be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question over here if anyone needs this.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1c2c5f88-766c-46b0-8cad-b9e2bf6e77e1/ssis-2017-scripting-language?forum=sqlintegrationservices